# Proper way to send data from Node to Angular for use in ng-repeat.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

Let me preface by saying I'm fairly new to Node and Angular.

I have two models, one for items, and another for users. My items model has an "owner" attribute which is the id of the user which created it. I have a angular controller for handling the items. In the items controller, I would like to create a function which accepts a user id and returns the associated username. Now, I have tried doing this two ways. One was making the list of users as resource and passing it to the items controller. I have also tried adding this code to the users server route and adding a corresponding $http.get in the user controller.

```
app.route('/users/:userId')
    .get(users.read);

app.param('userId', users.userByID);
```

I'm not sure which approach I should be using, and I run into trouble as soon as I attempt to ng-repeat the items in the view corresponding to the items controller, while calling my function on every "owner" attribute. I have been binding my data to $scope.ownerName. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use some kind of populate function like Mongoose does (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). In your case `item` to `user` is a 1 to many relationship. Each item does have one owner user and each user can have many items. Assuming your models `item` and `user` are also used on server side I would provide a server side method to populate a list of items and replace the owner field with the corresponding user. For example

```
items = [{id:"item1",owner:"user1"},{id:"item2",owner:"user2"}]
```

populated with

```
users = [{id:"user1",username:"user A"},{id:"user2",username:"user B"}]
```

results into

```
items = [
  {id:"item1",owner:{id:"user1",username:"user A"}},
  {id:"item2",owner:{id:"user2",username:"user B"}}
]
```

Then you can just access username of owner by calling

```
items[0].owner.username
```